# Is there a text file in IBM websphere that holds the important information

Tags: ibm, websphere

I need some important information to get/pull in IBM Websphere like it's Version, Installation Directory and etc. I wonder is there a text file that holds all of these or maybe a script that I can call/execute and retrieve these information?

Answer (score 5):

There is a `AboutThisProfile.txt` in the profile's logs directory, which contains a lot of information about the profile, e.g. the location, profile name, host name, port numbers, ...

For example:

```
$ cat /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/AboutThisProfile.txt
Application server environment to create: Application server
Location: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01
Disk space required: 200 MB
Profile name: AppSrv01
Make this profile the default: True
Node name: Node01
Host name: myservername.mydom.local
Enable administrative security (recommended): True
Administrative console port: 9060
Administrative console secure port: 9043
HTTP transport port: 8080
HTTPS transport port: 8443
Bootstrap port: 2809
SOAP connector port: 8880
Run application server as a service: True
Create a Web server definition: False
Performance tuning setting: Standard
```

Regarding the version, you can run `versionInfo.[sh|bat]` in the product's bin directory.

For example:

```
$ /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/versionInfo.sh
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2012; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.1.48, dated 2/8/12

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM WebSphere Product Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report at date and time April 5, 2016 9:39:47 PM EDT

Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Directory        /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
Version Directory        /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version
DTD Directory            /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/dtd
Log Directory            /var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs

Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBMJAVA7                 installed
ND                       installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition (Optional)
Version               7.0.4.1
ID                    IBMJAVA7
Build Level           gm1318.03
Build Date            5/10/13
Package               com.ibm.websphere.IBMJAVA.v70_7.0.4001.20130510_2103
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM WebSphere SDK for Java Technology Edition 7

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
Version               8.5.5.5
ID                    ND
Build Level           cf051507.01
Build Date            2/20/15
Package               com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5005.20150220_0158
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java
                      WebSphere Application Server Full Profile
                      EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```